# Set up port forwarding for 2 devices on same IP?

Tags: networking, router, port-forwarding, port

I am trying to set up port forwarding so that I can access two devices remotely.

I have succeeded in setting up the port forwarding, however I can only access one at a time.

I access the devices via the public ip address of the router.

The set up that works is:

`start port:80 end port:80 Translation start:80 Translation end: 80 - TCP`

Both devices are configured like this and as such I have to disable one to access to other.

How can I configure my port forwarding so that I can access both devices at the same time?

Comment: Use different external ports and point them to different internal devices. Any sensible software you use to connect should have a method to specify a nonstandard port. for example a webserver can easily be at `http://www.example.com:81/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. It's a fundamental law of how TCP/IP works: Only one endpoint at a time can handle incoming connections to an (IP-address/port) tuple.

What you **can** do instead are lots of well-understood solutions:

- Use different ports: This way you can access one device over `http://your.ip/` and the other via e.g. `http://your.ip:8080/`
- Set up a reverse proxy (or use one of the existing devices as one), then use virtual directories. This way you can access one device over `http://your.ip/one` and the other via e.g. `http://your.ip/two`
- Again et up a reverse proxy (or use one of the existing devices as one), then use virtual server host names. This way you can access one device over `http://your.first.hostname/` and the other via e.g. `http://your.second.hostname/`